# Run SQL for image “tagging” search function

Tags: php, html, sql, search

I am trying to get my code to run a search function which in theory runs a search for image "tagging" I have created my databases and the connection works fine. I have also set up 3 tables one for each part that plays for this "tag image search" to work. It is just when running the program and executing the code that it does not work and comes up with the following error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: searchesvale in C:\xampp\htdocs\galleryViewer\searchingtags.php on line 33
```

The code can be shown below with the "SQL Select statement" which is trying to run so when searching for a "particular image tag" this image will be retrieved from the gallery based on the "tag keyword search".

```
   $searchvalueentered = $_POST['searchvalue'];
$sql = "SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID FROM pictures, pictag, tagging WHERE pictures.idpic = '$searchvalue' AND pictag.tagpicID= '$searchvalue' AND tagging.tagpicID= '$searchvalue'";
```

Comment: You just asked the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622967/error-when-trying-to-run-sql-to-run-image-tagging-search-function

Comment: @relentless I have moved the variable above the sql select statement however, when executing the code it still does not run. would you recommend anything?
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT pictures.idpic, pictures.name, pictures.info, pictag.tagpicID, pictag.pictagName, tagging.IDimage, tagging.tagpicID FROM pictures, pictag, tagging WHERE pictures.idpic = '**$searchvalue**' AND pictag.tagpicID= '**$searchvalue**' AND tagging.tagpicID= '**$searchvalue**'";
```

Scroll to the right and I highlighted the variable `$searchvalue`. This error says that this variable is not defined. You have the variable `$searchvalueentered` defined, and `$_POST['searchvalue']`, but NOT `$searchvalue`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the variable to me, I am meant to be using the "$seachvalueentered", this was my error. However, when carrying out the search from this "tagging" key word no image is being displayed I feel it has something to do with the while loop as the images are to be printed here. could you offer any suggestion as to how to do this? Thank You